# Math equations not rendering when I knit from Rmd to Word

Tags: r-markdown, equation

I am using Microsoft Word V. 16 for Mac.  In an RStudio .rmd file, I want to create a math equation.  You see a preview of the equation in .rmd but the equation doesn't render when I knit to Word.  Any suggestions to help fix this issue so the equation will display instead of the code?  NOTE: it's not working for inline code or the "pop-out" code.

```
$\Large z \space score = \frac{(score \space  - \space mean)}{standard \space deviation}$
```

```
$$\Large z \space score = \frac{(score \space  - \space mean)}{standard \space deviation}$$
```

in .rmd:

[image: formula preview]]

in Word 2016 for mac:

[image: Word output]]

Answer (score 2):

This happens whenever pandoc does not know how to convert one or multiple LaTeX commands in the equation.

Use this instead:

```
$z \textrm{score} = \frac{(\textrm{score} - \textrm{mean})}{\textrm{standard  deviation}}$
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any addition resources to which I can refer for similar issues?

Comment: @zeigna No, sorry. You could raise any issue on the [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) mailing list where you'll reach pandoc's author and plenty of helpful people with deep knowledge of all things pandoc. The [texmath repo](https://github.com/jgm/texmath) would be a good place to request a missing feature; but asking on the mailing list first is appreciated.